# SQL subquery select from returned results

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) as count FROM gnb_full_log GROUP BY ip
```

This returns table with ip and count columns. I would like to select records with count = 1 OR 1 < count < 6

Answer (score 3):

Use a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT   ip, COUNT(*) as count
FROM     gnb_full_log
GROUP BY ip
HAVING   count = 1
```

Or

```
SELECT   ip, COUNT(*) as count
FROM     gnb_full_log
GROUP BY ip
HAVING   1 < count AND count < 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) as count 
FROM gnb_full_log GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(ip) >= 1 and COUNT(ip) < 6
```

HAVING clause is WHERE on aggregate function

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) as count FROM gnb_full_log GROUP BY ip HAVING  count > 1 AND count < 6
```